# C# TcpListener - client number limited

Tags: c#, .net, server, tcplistener

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

i am currently developing an online TCG in C#. The server runs perfectly fine on my own machine (quad-core, octa-thread Windows 7). I could connect 12 clients without problem. But when I launch it on a server, the maximum amount of clients becomes limited to the number of processor cores on the machine. I ran the code on a single-core Windows 2016 Server and could not connect more that one client to start a game. Then I ran the server on a quad-core Windows 2012 Server and could only connect four clients and start two games. Any further clients got completely ignored until someone disconnects. Then the new client gets accepted and the server crashes.

The server is a MS Visual Studio 2015 Windows Forms Application with .NET Framework 4.0. The Windows Server machines have .NET Framework 4.0 and my own machine has version 4.5.

I will gladly provide any additional information you may require and answer all your questions.

Server code in C#:

```
public void Init()
{
    try {
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        server.Start();
        serverRunning = true;
        server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient, server);
        OutputTB.Text = "server has been started on port " + port.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        OutputTB.Text = "socket error: " + e.Message;
    }
}

private void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult newClient)
{
    if (!serverRunning)
        return;
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient, server);

    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)newClient.AsyncState;
    ServerClient client = new ServerClient(listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(newClient));
    Send("SWHO", client);
    connectedClients.Add(client);
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        ClientListBox.Items.Add("Waiting for authentification...");
    });

    NetworkStream stream = client.tcp.GetStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, true);
    while (client.connected && serverRunning) {
        if (stream.DataAvailable) {
            string data = reader.ReadLine();
            if (data != null)
                OnIncomingData(client, data);
        }
    }
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        if (client.authenticated)
            ClientListBox.Items.Remove(client.playerName);
        else
            ClientListBox.Items.Remove("Waiting for authentification...");
    });
    Send("SDISC", client);
    waitingClients.Remove(client);
    connectedClients.Remove(client);
    client.tcp.Close();
}

private void OnIncomingData()
{
    //process client data
}
```

Comment: I would pull the authentication piece out of AcceptTcpClient(). Maybe it can't release the thread until the callback returns or something. Accept the connection and get out of there. Maybe use a state machine or something to indicate that you're waiting for the client to authenticate so the next time you read data, you know how to handle it.

Comment: Could you reduce this to just the server accepting the connection and nothing else (so that it still repros)? That would simplify the issue. Did you reconfigure your thread pool, btw? This smells of thread pool exhaustion which is unusual (and a bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread pool exhaustion it was! Big thanks to itsme86 and usr for the helpful tips. Now the code looks like this:

```
private void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient, server);
    Task.Run(() => ListenToIncomingData(IAsyncResult ar);
}
```

There is one thing I'm curious about: doesn't the asynchronous call also consume a thread? how come there are enough resources to handle it but not enough to handle the unfinished callback?

Comment: A more important question is: Why did you run out of threads? Normally, the runtime has no trouble spawning them into the hundreds. Async IO does not consume threads at all, but Task.Run is not async IO. So that does consume one thread from the same pool that you used before. It's mysterious why it works now. There should still be *some* work starved out.

Comment: it's even more mysterious that the old version worked on my windows. the problem only occured on the servers. they are virtual machines. maybe that was the problem?

Comment: These VMs likely have less cores causing less threads to be made available. To me this sounds like someone in your process did ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Env.ProcessorCount).

Comment: the funny thing is that the restriction only applied when i stayed in the acceptClient() callback. now i let the callback finish and listen in another function and this problem does not occur anymore.